# Respostas de e-mails (imap/pop3)

Tags: php, smtp, imap, pop3

Estou com um problema num projecto em que faço uma gestão dos e-mail.

Ideia: Listar os e-mails. Ao entrar num e-mail, listar todas as respostas ao e-mail

Problema: Para saber se um e-mail é resposta de outro e-mail estou a usar o campo "references" que vem da função "imap_headerinfo".
Isto funciona em muitos casos. O grande problema é quando o campo "message_id" vem vazio. Isto faz com que o valor que vem do campo "references" seja:
"xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx  xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx"
Ele retorna no meio um espaço em branco. Desta forma eu não consigo saber qual o e-mail que pertence ali.

Existe outra forma de saber que o e-mail é resposta de outro e-mail?

Comment: Cole um pedaço do seu código para a gente ver.